# how to call php page to work in background?

Tags: php, jquery, phpmailer, pear

I am working on an email system , All things go fine , I can send email without any error, I have more than 3000 email address and I want to send email to them , but when I press on send button the operation took more than one hour , so I decided to use pear queue mail package, the package now insert the emails queue inside database, but how can I run send function after inserting it in database in background so user will not get confused from a long time that he had to wait .

Answer (score -1):

using loop is a long process to send email one by one it is better to send bulk email. [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) is best to do that.

use SwiftMailer, which has HTML support, support for different mime types and SMTP authentication (there are very low chances that your email will go into spam).

also, I would like to tell you when you run a long process in PHP it gets time out after some time. you have to increase the execution time in php.ini file.
if you want to stuck with your process(loop).